# Swap X and Y axes on Numbers 3.1

Tags: iwork, numbers, graph

[This link](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/4529/swap-x-and-y-axes-in-numbers) is now outdated with the new release of numbers.

I want to transpose the X- and Y-axes on a chart in Numbers 3.1. How the heck can I do this?

The first chart I made was able to sum my columns up to 100 just fine:
[image: Correct display]

However, when I try it with fewer columns/geographies, it transposes the selection:
[image: Incorrect display]

Even when I transpose the cells, it still forces the data to display incorrectly and there is no option to swap the axes:
[image: Still incorrect display]

I'm so frustrated with this! How can I make it plot correctly? Thanks!

Comment: It looks like if I build a chart from scratch (i.e., don't select any text and just click the chart button), then I can select the transposed cells (image 3) and it will work that way. It's stupid to have to workaround it like that.

Comment: Please shift that comment to an answer if it has solved your problem. That allows others to see that the question is answered.

Comment: It wasn't a very good answer, but Aidan below did answer it correctly. I will do so next time if my own answer is sufficient ;)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Was having the same problem – apparently the options to swap axes moved to the bottom left when Editing Data References:

[image: options]

Answer found [here](https://discussions.apple.com/message/24642568#24642568).

Comment: Yes! This is what solves the problem! Thanks for referencing the thread.

Comment: Note: this is at the bottom of the window.